# Exclusion of elements in a Java file

Tags: java

I have some doubts about the garbage collector and how I can clear memory in Java.

I have a program that writes a binary search tree to a file and I made a function that inserts an element and another that removes an element, but in the method that removes I put the elements that I remove in a space in the file that I call "empty blocks" (which is a stack). In the C language there is a method that freed the memory that was `free()`, in Java there is the garbage collector that is at the discretion of Java. How can I free the memory of these blocks in the file (elements excluded).

Is there a way to free the memory of an element on file in Java (the element is of type int)?

Comment: Hello. Please see: [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676) Use [edit] option and translate it to English OR move it (delete it from here and repost in proper place) to appropriate StackExchange site which is using your language (if such exists - visit linked post to find list of sites about programming problems in other languages).

Comment: Java is not C.  The garbage collector manages memory deallocation.  Java memory is freed when all references to a class instance or primitive value have expired (gone out of scope).

Comment: Memory is freed when you no longer has a reference to it. If you reference is from a stack called `emptyBlocks`, then you're preventing the garbage collector from freeing it. Get rid of that stack, and the memory will be freed.

Comment: I understand, so java manages automatically, I can even mark it using Finalize, but it wouldn't be practical, thanks for the answers.

Comment: Turn off your CAPS LOCK key.

Answer (score 0):

> I put the elements that I remove in a space in the file that I call “empty blocks ”(Which is a stack)

Whatever data structure you use to track your data will be in an object of some class.

When that object no longer has any references pointing to it, that object becomes a candidate for garbage collection. No need for you to do anything except not hang on to any reference longer than needed.

The garbage collector may clear the unneeded object immediately, or may clear it later. Either way, we as Java programmers do not care. Eventually the memory will be freed up.

- If the reference variable pointing to an object is a local variable, that reference is dropped when the local variable goes out of scope.
- If the reference variable is a member field on another object, the
  object in question will be released when the other object becomes
  garbage.
- If the reference variable is `static`, you should assign `null` explicitly to let the referenced object become garbage. In Java, `static` variables stay in memory throughout the execution run of your app.

In the first two cases, you can release the object sooner by setting the reference variable to `null`. Generally this is not needed, but doing so may be wise if a large amount of memory is at stake. Ditto if other precious resources are being needlessly held.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to free the memory of an element on file in Java (the element is of type int)?

Your question is really hard to understand, but I *think* you are asking about freeing up disk blocks in a data structure *stored in a file*<sup>1</sup>.

There is no Java support for this.  If you write a data structure to a file, the problem of reclaiming space in the file is yours, not Java's.  Indeed, I don't think that a typical OS will allow you to (literally) free disk blocks in the middle of a file<sup>2</sup>.

There may be 3rd-party libraries that support this kind of thing, but I don't have the background knowledge to make a recommendation.

---

If I have *correctly* understood what you are asking, your discussion of C's malloc / free versus Java's garbage collection is only peripherally relevant.  Both of these schemes are for managing memory, not space in a random access file.  Now you could conceivably implement similar schemes for managing space in a file, but you would need to take account of the different characteristics of memory and disk I/O.  (Even if you are mapping the file into memory.)

---

<sup>1 - If you are actually talking about managing objects in heap memory in Java, your best bet is to just let the garbage collector deal with it; see [Basil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67259133/139985).  There are also 3rd-party libraries for storing objects in off-heap memory, but it is unclear if they would help you.  I understand that such libraries typically leave it to the programmer to decide when to free an object.  (They are not garbage collected.)

2 - It would be a bad idea.  If the disk blocks thus freed were then used in a different file, you would get a lot of file fragmentation.  That would be bad for file I/O performance.</sup>